# How to close space after hiding table columns

Tags: jquery

I have a 'general purpose' table which consists of 9 columns. The table is filled by a client. The 1st 3 columns and the last column are mandatory fields. The remaining 5 columns are optional. Client can fill 1 or all 5 optional columns in between these mandatory columns. The client decides the title/header of the 5 optional columns. These headers are extracted from the client form filled before the client gets to this table.
For simplicity I am showing only 3 rows and these columns. In practice, the columns can be up to 35 and the rows can be up to 500. Also the finish button is part of an earlier form (not described here). When clicked, a table with choice of columns selected by the client will be displayed.
The data in this table feeds other tables & involves calculation at different stages. At the end, client can view & print these tables and all other reports (not described here) associated with this table.
So far my data transfer, calculations etc are all OK. Except for view & print of this table. While my script hides BLANK columns (on click finish), the SPACE for the blank column is still SHOWING. WORST if client uses only 1 column out of the 5 Optional columns.
I do not wish to use a checkbox or special button to hide unused optional columns as advised in some solution I come across.
One solution I am thinking of is to rotate the table left by 90 degrees so that all thead will be vertical and on the left. This method will hide the empty rows without leaving SPACE. If possible, I do not want to use this method.
Please have a look at the 2 scripts I have tried but didnt REMOVE the SPACE. Advise on how to remove the space left behind when the columns are hidden. Note there are some calculations after this step using row, cell index.
Below the css:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    body {font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica,Sans-serif;}
    th,td {font-size: 12px; border: 1px; border-style: solid; margin: 0px; border-spacing: 0px;}
    .btn {font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; max-width: 75px;}
    .btn:hover {background-color: rgb(0,250,0);}        
    .hidetf {visibility: hidden; width: 0px; height: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; margin: 0px;}
    </style>
```

Next the html:

```
            <table id='sdtbl'>
    <caption id='sdtblhdr'></caption>
    <thead> 
    <tr>
    <th>s/n</th>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>Names</th>      
    <th>SCRD2tpf</th>
    <th>YHUJ56ty</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th>Remarks</th>        
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>     
    <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>PKC1</td>
    <td>LCT1</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>        
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>PKC2</td>
    <td>LCT2</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>        
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>PKC3</td>
    <td>LCT3</td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>        
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td><input type="text"></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>       
    <tfoot> 
    <tr>
    <td class='hidetf'></td>
    <td class='hidetf'></td>
    <td>Summary</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>           
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    </table>
    <br>        
    <input class='btn' onclick="finish()" value="Finish"></p>
```

And here are the scripts i have tried separately:

```
    <script>
    function finish(){
        var sdtbl = document.getElementById('sdtbl');
        var x = sdtbl.rows[0].cells.length;
        var y = sdtbl.rows.length;  
        //Hide unused Bonus & Deduction payroll headers
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            var hdr = sdtbl.rows[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[i];
            var val = hdr.innerHTML;        
            if (val === "") {
                $('#sdtbl tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(i);
                for (var j = 1; j < y; j++) {                       
                    $('#sdtbl tr').eq(j).find('td').eq(i);              
                }           
            }       
        }
    }
    </script>



    <script>
    function finish(){
        var sdtbl = document.getElementById('sdtbl');
        var x = sdtbl.rows[0].cells.length;
        var y = sdtbl.rows.length;  
        //Hide unused Bonus & Deduction payroll headers
        for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            var hdr = sdtbl.rows[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[i];
            var val = hdr.innerHTML;        
            if (val === "") {
                hdr.setAttribute('class', 'hidetf');
                for (var j = 1; j < y; j++) {                       
                    sdtbl.rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i].setAttribute('class', 'hidetf');                
                }           
            }       
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I think the question is: "How to hide/remove unused columns in the table?"

Comment: As you will notice in my write up I can hide & unhide columns. When I hide columns, yes the columns get hidden but the space between adjacent columns still remains. I have used the two scripts; One leaves a blank space without boarder. The other still show the boarders with tiny width. I have used max-width: 0px, max-height: 0px with same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have just found out the error in my script. The 1st script works fine after correcting the error. I should have used th for the header row as I did in the html and not td. Also I have added the missing .hide()
The 2nd script though hides the columns but will still show a space for any column it hides.
Note that the correct script had been posted earlier but with toggle buttons, check box etc which didn't suite my desire.
This script works fine without checkbox or toggle button.

```
<script>
function finish(){
    var sdtbl = document.getElementById('sdtbl');
    var x = sdtbl.rows[0].cells.length;
    var y = sdtbl.rows.length;  
    //Hide unused Bonus & Deduction payroll headers
    for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        var hdr = sdtbl.rows[0].getElementsByTagName('th')[i];
        var val = hdr.innerHTML;        
        if (val === "") {
            $('#sdtbl tr').eq(0).find('th').eq(i).hide();
            for (var j = 1; j < y; j++) {                       
                $('#sdtbl tr').eq(j).find('td').eq(i).hide();              
            }           
        }       
    }
}
</script>
```